# run a shell script in a python function and get data from the script

Tags: python, bash

I am about to write a python script that will call one or more shell scripts. I cannot execute certain commands using just python, so I am forced to run shell scripts in a python function.

Now, I would like to know if is possible to get any data from the shell script: I assume that I can get the exit code from the script, using subprocess.Popen, but is that all that I can get back from the shell script?

Ideally I don't need a ton of things, but I would like to set the shell script to return X or Y if the process pass or fail, and Z in case something goes bad but it depends from a specific cause, and pass this to the python function, that will act accordingly.

Is this possible or am I wasting time trying to integrate the two?

Comment: It is indeed possible. Read the docs on `subprocess` completely. You might specifically want to take a look at `check_output`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE; STDOUT

pyversion = sys.version_info.major

class interact():
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.handle = Popen(c, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
        sleep(1)
    def send(self, what):
        for c in what:
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            if pyversion == 3:
                self.handle.stdin.write(bytes(c, 'UTF-8'))
            else:
                self.handle.stdin.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.handle.stdin.flush()
            sleep(0.05)
    def getrow(self):
        return self.handle.stdout.readline()
    def poll(self):
        return self.handle.poll()
    def done(self):
        if self.poll() == 1:
            return 'Return Y'
        return 'Return X'
    def close(self):
        self.handle.stdout.close()
        self.handle.stdin.close()
```

You can do something like this, where you have your own structure and return whatever you want depending on the exit code or current run-code which is `None` if the process havn't finished.

Simply use it as:

```
handle = interact('ls -lah')
while handle.poll() is None:
    pass
result = handle.done()
```

Or tweek it, i've used this code for a basic structure when doing SSH calls and for genering OpenSSL keys, works like a charm but i think i had to tweek it in order for it to work with SSH (can't find the code atm)

Something you could add is a:

```
try:
    self.handle.stdin.write(...)
except:
    self.error = True
```

and at the `done()` you simply return `Z` (as you mentioned) if an error has occured.

**Note:** If you don't call `getrow()` on a heavy outputting script/command the buffer will overflow and hang the entire thing, so make sure you tap that once in a while or remove `stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT`.

Answer (score 0):

Using subprocess:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-ltr'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
ret = p.wait()
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

I would not use `shell` argument since it will just complicate your life. If you want to do things asynchronously you can use `poll()` instead of `wait()`.

For more information, read subprocess docs:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: This way you have no control over the `stdout` tho, and as mentioned you might overflow the buffert and end up with a application that hangs :) `shell` doesn't complicate your life, if anything it makes it easier?